# Why does my realm notification token only trigger on my active device and not all devices with the open realm?

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, realm

I'm newly learning iOS/swift programming and developing an application using MongoDB Realm and using Realm sync. I'm new to programming and realm, so please feel free to correct any terminology. My question is about listening for realm notifications, which I see referred to as change listeners and notification tokens. Regardless, here is the info:

My application has a list of locations with a status (confirmed/pending/cancelled). I open this list from my realm as a realm managed object and create my notification handler:

```
//This is called in it's own function, but assigns the locations 
locations = publicRealm?.objects(Location.self)
    
//This is run after the function is called 
self?.notificationToken = self?.locations!.observe { [weak self] (_) in
                                  self?.tableView.reloadData() 
print("Notification Token!!!")
```

I then populate my table view and let a user tap on a location, which passes the location and realm to another view controller where the user can update the status. That update is made in a separate view controller.

```
    do{
        try publicRealm?.write {
            selectedLocation?.statusMessage = locationStatusTextField.text!
            selectedLocation?.status = selectedStatus
        }
    }catch{
        print("Error saving location data: \(error)")
    }
```

At this point my notification token is successfully triggered on the device where I am making the location update. The change is shown immediately. However there is no notification token or realm refresh that happens on any other open devices that are showing the locations table view. They do not respond to the change, and will only respond to it if I force realm.refresh(). The change is showing in Atlas on MongoDB server, though.

I am testing on multiple simulators and my own personal phone as well, all in Xcode.

I'm very confused how my notification token can trigger on one device but not another.

When I first started the project it was a much simpler realm model and I could run two devices in simulator and updating one would immediately fire a change notification and cause the second device to show the correct notification.

I have since updated to a newer realm version and also made the realm model more complicated. Though for this purpose I am trying to keep it simple by doing all changes via swift and in one realm.

I also have realm custom user functions running and changing data but I think reading the docs I am realizing that those will not trigger a notification - I'm not sure if that's true though? I just know right now that if I change data in the DB via a user function no notifications are triggered anywhere - but if I do realm.refresh() then the change shows.

What is it that I am missing in how I am using these notifications?

***Updating information on Public Realm:

Save the realm:
var publicRealm:Realm?

Login as an anon user and then open the realm:

```swift
    let configuration = user.configuration(partitionValue: "PUBLIC")

    Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: configuration) { [weak self](result) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        switch result {
                        case .failure(let error):
                            fatalError("Failed to open realm: \(error)")
                        case .success(let publicRealm):
                            self!.publicRealm = publicRealm
                            
                            guard let syncConfiguration = self?.publicRealm?.configuration.syncConfiguration else {
                                fatalError("Sync configuration not found! Realm not opened with sync?")
                            }
```

It is after this realm opening that the locations are loaded and notification token is created.

I use a segue to pass the location object and realm to the next VC:

```swift
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! UpdateLocationViewController
        destinationVC.delegate = self
        
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destinationVC.selectedLocation = locations?[indexPath.row]
        }
        
        if indexPathRow != nil {
            destinationVC.selectedLocation = locations?[indexPathRow!]
        }
        
        destinationVC.publicRealm = self.publicRealm
    }
```

Some notes:

- original public realm opened by anon user
- only a logged in user can click on a location... so in the 'UpdateLocation' VC that gets passed the public realm I am a logged in user. But, I'm just using the Dev mode of Realm to allow me to read/write however I like...  and I am writing straight to that public realm to try and keep it simple. (I have a custom user function that writes to both public and the user's org realm, but I stopped trying to use the function for now)
- I identify the object to update based on the passed in location object from the first VC

Comment: Welcome to SO! You've done a pretty good job in asking a clear question and it seems like you're on the right path. Generally speaking, when you observe a results object, any changes to that object will fire a notification. However, there are things that can make it not work; for example if the objects are on different threads. Or. If you're writing data on a background thread with no run loop. In that case calling realm.refresh() forces a runloop which then updates the data. So, the issue is probably tied to `publicRealm1` - can you include that in your question?

Comment: Thanks Jay! To be frank, I don't fully understand threading beyond what I think is async is a background thread and then anything happening in the VC is main.

I thought this could be causing my problem, but also don't understand how my notification token (which I think comes from Realm server?) could be getting triggered in one app instance but not another. I'm updating my original post now.

Comment: I've been reading more on threading and I see my understanding was wrong above. Though I'm not forcing anything onto any background threads so I think I should be good with everything in main.

Comment: You *really* need to read [Realm Threading](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/advanced-guides/threading/) noting this  - *By offloading heavy work to background threads, the UI thread can remain highly responsive regardless of the size of the workload*. Also take a look at the tutorial; you'll want to update your .observe code but more importantly, note they do not pass Realms around. They pass the realm configuration and then each viewController maintains it's own connection.

Comment: I've read through it and will do so some more as I keep growing the app. Thanks for checking over my question!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use try! when making my write call rather than just try. I updated my write blocks as such:

```swift
   try! publicRealm?.write {
              selectedLocation?.statusMessage = locationStatusTextField.text!
                selectedLocation?.status = selectedStatus
            }
```

Just wanted to follow up in case anyone finds this. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for posting this but it's not related to anything in the question and can actually be dangerous and lead to crashes that are hard to track down. A `do/try/throw/catch` block (as in your question) is there to handle errors e.g. try this function and if it fails catch the error and handle it. Using 'try!' guarantees there will never be an error and therefore there is no error handling; that can be an issue especially when it comes to working with async functions on the internet. Bottom line though is they are functionally *identical* so will have no impact on the question.

Comment: Oh, see Hacking With Swift [try, catch, do and throw](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-error-handling-try-catch)

Comment: I understand and agree, and am still researching to implement a better solution. 

However, this did in fact answer my question and lead to correct notification functionality. This is how realm handles it in their iOS task tracker instructional app I noticed.

Comment: I just don't want other users to adopt this as it will cause application crashes. e.g. if publicRealm will never be nil and never throw, then this `try! publicRealm?.write` would be unnecessary - it would be just `publicRealm.write` like `x = 0` as it cannot fail. However, publicRealm *can* be nil if `Realm.asyncOpen` fails and it *can* throw if the write doesn't complete - therefore a crash would happen. It's not clear why using `try!` instead of `do/try/throw/catch` works because they are functionally identical other than perhaps you are already getting an error and `try!`is not handling it?